# Filtering a collection based on the existence of an object in each hasMany in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to filter an instance of `Ember.Enumerable` based on the existence of an object in each items `hasMany` association.

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend
  users: DS.hasMany 'user', async: true

App.User = DS.Model.extend()
```

How can I filter a collection of projects based on the existence of an individual user object in each projects `users` array?

```
user = @store.find('user', 1)
@store.find('project').filter (project) ->
  project.get('users').then (users) ->
    users.contains(user)
```

Because my `users` property is `async: true` on the `Project` model, calling `project.get('users')` returns a promise, which in turn is being returned from the `filter()` call. Instead, I want to return whether or not the `users` array contains the `user` object.

This may be a simple question. I'm still getting my hands dirty with javascript promises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem is here:

```
  project.get('users').then (users) ->
```

`then`'s first parameter is the callback that you'd use on success, not the resulting response.  So you should do it more like this:

```
user = @store.find('user', 1)
@store.find('project').filter(project) ->
    users = project.get('users').then() ->
    users.contains(user)
```

Apologies if my syntax isn't quite right.  I"m not very familiar with Coffeescript.

Comment: In the line `project.get('users').then (users) ->`, the first argument to `then` is a function with the parameter `users`. So, it compiles to something like `project.get('users').then(function(users) { ...`